# Rebus: Romance, Cats and a Pen

Tags: visual, rebus

[image]

Find X, Y and Z from the above rebus.

Comment: in my opinion they can be multiple answers to this question.

Comment: I assume there will be only a single answer. Single X, Y Z values that will satisfy the equations. If no one makes any progress, I will post a hint tomorrow.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I know one:

> Y is Sylvester Stallone. (Sylvester the cat, and he's on stall).

Update. Thanks to [manshu](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/17482/manshu) and [Will](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/17147/will) :-)

> X is James Cameron (Cameron is an anagram of `romance`.)

And

> If X and Y are correct, then Z is Rambo : First Blood II. (X and Y wrote it together.)

Comment: and that symbol is 'on'

Comment: @manshu ye, that too (green).

Comment: x=james cameron coz cameron is anagram

Comment: @ABcDexter: Y is correct.

Comment: @Will I was about to check romantic partners of [James Bond](https://www.quora.com/How-many-women-has-James-Bond-slept-with)

Comment: @manshu: Post it as an answer

Comment: @AeJey do you know that i started from Z, and had a strong vibe that Z was Alfred 'PEN'nyworth. I am still skeptical about it.

Comment: I think you got the Z now. :) Check the answer by Will

Answer (score 12):

[Manshu](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/28181/) and [ABcDexter](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/28180/) have done almost all the work

Their answers lead to

> Z = Rambo: First Blood Part II

Which has a screenplay written by X and Y

Comment: Exactly. :) Whose answer should I accept. :( I am confused.

Comment: @Will good. I really digressed into SciFi part :-0

Comment: @ABcDexter You should add this to your answer so that AeJey has a complete one to accept :)

Comment: @Will You should have taken the honour.

Answer (score 9):

X =

> James Cameron

Because.

> 007 = James Bond. Therefore half of 007 = James. *Cameron* is anagram of *Romance*.

Comment: X is correct. :)